# trigonometric problems mainly conversion in triangle

Tags: trigonometry

The number of degrees in one acute angle of aright angled triangle is equal to the number of grades in the other ;express both the angle in degrees.

Comment: Aside from the definition of "grades", what do you know about the angles of a right triangle?

Comment: @HemantaPaul Remember $1grad =\frac{9}{10}deg$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the sum of the two angles in degrees then it is evident that $X_1+X_2=90$ and as you say the number of degrees in one angle let $X_1$ is equal to the number of grades in the other let $X_2$ i.e $X_1=\frac{9}{10}(X_2)$ put this value in the first equation and solve.

Comment: thank you,actually i got confused by the question,i thought there was  2 triangles.